# Unresolved external '__fastcall Idsmtp::TIdSMTP::~TIdSMTP()'

Tags: c++builder, indy, rad-studio, c++builder-xe

I have installed RAD Studio XE (C++Builder XE).
When compiling a project, I'm getting an error:

> [Linker Error] Unresolved external '__fastcall Idsmtp::TIdSMTP::~TIdSMTP()'

`TIdSMTP` is available in Indy. How to install Indy for RAD Studio XE?

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Indy is pre-installed in the IDE. You shouldn't need to install anything. Just make sure your project is configured properly so it is linking to the Indy library files. That being said, XE (and the Indy that comes with it) is quite old, why not use a modern version?

Comment: @Remy, how to install Indy? Only source code is available in GitHub.

Comment: Did you read the documentation that is in that GitHub repo? https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy

Comment: @Remy. Thanks. I referred some other Github repo link. I will try out with the github link you suggested.